# How to show redux props on Component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a problem to show array from actions to the component(Dashboard).

When I use `this.props.Cards` direct in Render I can see the array.

But when I add directly to `componentDidMount` I can't see just`undefined`.

Here you go, my code:

Dashboard.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Header from '../../common/Header/'
import Masonry from '../../common/Masonry/'
import { cardAction } from '../../store/actions/Cards'
import Arrow_Down from '../../assets/img/arrow-down.svg'

class Dashboard extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('show all cards', this.props.cardAction())
  }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      collapsed: true,
      class: 'collapsed',
      showCards: []
    }
    this.toggleCollapse = this.toggleCollapse.bind(this);
  }

  toggleCollapse(i) {
    console.log('i', i)
    this.setState({
      collapsed: !this.state.collapsed,
      class: this.state.collapsed ? '' : 'collapsed',
      showCards: this.state.Cards
    });
    console.log(this.state.showCards)
  }

  render() {
    console.log('cards', this.props.Cards)
    console.log('pre push-a', this.state.showCards)
    // this.state.showCards.push('test')
    // console.log('posle push-a', this.state.showCards)
    const cardList = this.props.Cards.map((info, i) => {
      return (
        <div className={(info.open === 'true') ? 'collapsed' : ''} key={i}>
          <div className='header flex space-between'>
            <h2>{info.title}</h2>
            <span onClick={() => { this.toggleCollapse(i) }}><img src={Arrow_Down} alt='Arrow' /></span>
          </div>
          <div className='content'>
            <p>{info.description}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    })
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Masonry columns={3} gap={20}>
          {cardList}
        </Masonry>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

Dashboard.defaultProps = {
  columns: 2,
  gap: 20,
  Cards: []
}
Dashboard.propTypes = {
  Cards: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { Cards: state.cards.result }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  cardAction: () => dispatch(cardAction())
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Dashboard)
```

Actions --> Card.js

```js
const cards_array = [
  {
    title: 'title',
    description: 'Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttito',
    open: 'true'
  },
  {
    title: 'title2',
    description: 'Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttito Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttito',
    open: 'true'
  },
  {
    title: 'title3',
    description: 'Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttito Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttito Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttito',
    open: 'true'
  },
  {
    title: 'title',
    description: 'Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttito',
    open: 'false'
  },
  {
    title: 'title2',
    description: 'Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttito Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttito',
    open: 'true'
  },
  {
    title: 'title3',
    description: 'Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttito Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttito Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttito',
    open: 'true'
  },
  {
    title: 'title3',
    description: 'Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttito Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttito Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttito',
    open: 'false'
  },
  {
    title: 'title',
    description: 'Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttito',
    open: 'true'
  },
  {
    title: 'title2',
    description: 'Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttito Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttito',
    open: 'true'
  }
]

export const cardAction = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: 'FETCH_CARDS',
    payload: cards_array
  })
}
```

Reducers --> Cards.js

```js
import { updateObject } from '../Utility'


const getCards = (state, action) => {
  return updateObject(state, { result: action.payload })
}
export default (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_CARDS':
      return getCards(state, action)
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Comment: `this.props.cardAction` function just dispatch an action to fetch cards. It doesn't really returns the result. The redux will update the store according to that action which will rerender the component to show the updated state.

Comment: I tried to use `console.log('show all cards', this.props.Cards)` But I have the same problem. 
What I need to do to set Cards to state?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you have any problem here. Calling `this.props.cardAction` in `componentDidMount` will go ahead to fetch cards and it will be available via `this.props.Cards`. Naturally, you would not expect `this.props.Card` to show after being called.

BTW, because React re-renders when new props come in, you get to see it immediately in the render function because the data is not delayed in some way. But initially, it would be `undefined`.

Comment: I want to do this
`componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ showCards: this.props.Cards })
  }` 
How I can do that

Comment: Oh! No. You shouldn't do that. Whatever is gotten from props don't need to be set to the state except in some rare cases. It's so an anti-pattern.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand that.
But, how to show this, it's `undefined`
`componentDidMount() { console.log('show all cards', this.props.Cards) }`

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are consoling `this.props.cardAction()`. By executing action `cardAction`, `Cards` prop will only be updated. You are getting `undefined` because redux action doesn't return anything. When you execute action, state will be updated which in return update the prop of component.

Comment: Could you please show me. I'm not sure that I understand you :)

Comment: When you are writing ‘console.log(someFunction())’ you expect that that function would return something e.g. a string and you are consoling that string. But in redux action doesn’t return anything it only updates redux state which in return updates the prop of connected component due to which component is rerended.